# Wrong characters for accents in one Windows-1252 encoded XML

Tags: c#, .net, xml

In the XML i need to read in C#, i find characters such as

> `Ã©, Ã‰.`

As far as i know , i should not find those characters in a windows-1252 encoded XML. Can i fix that problem in C# or the XML itself must be updated?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is UTF8, not Windows-1252. To be precise `é, É`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does look like the XML needs to be updated.

You could certainly write something that reads it in as the UTF-8 it really is and writes it back out as the Windows-1252 it claimed to be, but why bother? XML in Windows-1252 is like someone using their smart-phone while dressed ye olde knight at a Renaissance Faire anyway. Just drop the incorrect declaration from the first line and away you go.

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is: you're probably using the wrong encoding. From this I'd say you should be using UTF-8. You can force it by downloading the document before parsing it.

I should note that downloading URL's is tricky: web servers often report the wrong encoding. That is also the reason why the HTML5 standard includes a section on encoding detection. I'm afraid there's no easy generic solution for this -- we ended up implementing our own encoding detection algorithms for our web crawlers.